# Application is not responding

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**What the application should do**

This application should take the input of time (seconds, minutes and hours) and shutdown the computer after that time. It should also update the text box with how long left until the computer has shut down.

**What the application actually does**

I had an issue that I 'fixed' where the called ac across threads weren't safe, so I fixed it and I don't get that error now. However, the updateThread doesn't update and print the time left; and the text box doesn't get "test" appended to it. The UI also becomes Not Responding. Any help would be much appreciated.

Also, if you see anything else that could be done better, please comment and explain. Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ShutdownPC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int inputHours;
        int inputMinutes;
        int inputSeconds;

        Thread sleepingThread;
        Thread updatingThread;

        NotifyIcon shutdownPCIcon;
        Icon defaultIcon;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            defaultIcon = new Icon("defaultIcon.ico");
            shutdownPCIcon = new NotifyIcon();
            shutdownPCIcon.Icon = defaultIcon;
            shutdownPCIcon.Visible = true;

            MenuItem progNameMenuItem = new MenuItem("ShutdownPC by Conor");
            MenuItem breakMenuItem = new MenuItem("-");
            MenuItem quitMenuItem = new MenuItem("Quit");
            ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(progNameMenuItem);
            contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(breakMenuItem);
            contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(quitMenuItem);
            shutdownPCIcon.ContextMenu = contextMenu;

            shutdownPCIcon.Text = "ShutdownPC";

            quitMenuItem.Click += QuitMenuItem_Click;
        }

        private void QuitMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            shutdownPCIcon.Dispose();
            sleepingThread.Abort();
            updatingThread.Abort();
            this.Close();
        }

        public void sleepThread()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(sleepThread));
            }
            else {
                textBox1.Enabled = false;
                textBox2.Enabled = false;
                textBox3.Enabled = false;
                button1.Enabled = false;

                int totalMilliseconds = ((inputHours * 3600) + (inputMinutes * 60) + inputSeconds) * 1000;
                Thread.Sleep(totalMilliseconds);
                //Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
                richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format("test"));
            }
        }

        public void updateThread()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(updateThread));
            }
            else {
                int totalSeconds = (inputHours * 3600) + (inputMinutes * 60) + inputSeconds;
                while (totalSeconds > 0)
                {
                    TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalSeconds);

                    string timeOutput = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

                    richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format(timeOutput));
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    richTextBox1.Clear();
                    totalSeconds--;
                }
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            inputHours = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            inputHours = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            inputMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            inputMinutes = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            inputSeconds = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
            inputSeconds = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updatingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(updateThread));
            updatingThread.Start();
            sleepingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sleepThread));
            sleepingThread.Start();
        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to create new Threads for such an action, give System.Timers.Timer or System.Windows.Forms.Timer a shot!

Comment: Or await Task.Delay -- but John is right; this is what a timer is for.  This short program is full of bad practices; do not use threads like this.  There's no need to use any extra threads for a simple task like this.

Comment: Agree with John. It's simplest way for this case. But in case of understanding thread programming you should review my answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Invoke in the beginning of method that runs in separate thread is bad idea, because all code runs in GUI thread and lock it.

You should Invoke only GUI updating code!!!